# Finding maximum number of rows created per hour?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have a table to store product reviews like this:

```
Id -int
ProductId -int
Timestamp -datetime
Comments -text
```

Is there an easy way to count and determine the rate of reviews a product has received in any 60 minute timespan?  ie. Widget1 maximum reviews/hour is 55.

working with sql05.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the SQL DATEPART functions like this:

```
SELECT
    DAY(TimeStamp), MONTH(TimeStamp), YEAR(TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp),
    COUNT(*)
FROM    
    dbo.Products
GROUP BY
    DAY(TimeStamp), MONTH(TimeStamp), YEAR(TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp)
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

This gives you not just the maximum number of views for any given hour, but all of them, sorted by the frequency. Mind you: other than RexM's solution, this is based on the "hour" part of your "timestamp" - so if you have quite a few views at 7:59 and another burst at 8:01, in my solution, those wouldn't be shown together (since one is hour=7 and the other is hour=8).

If you need the "any 60-minute timespan" approach, use RexM's basic idea (DATEDIFF with minutes <= 60).

Marc

Comment: Nice alternative. I realized after I finished brushing the dust off my SQL brain that the OP wants LINQ to SQL, not SQL. (Also explicitly says 'any 60 minute timespan')

Comment: Don't see any mention of Linq-to-SQL (other than the tag), and yes, I noticed the "any 60-minute span" - that's quite a bit trickier though. Maybe this approach will do - we'll see - up to the OP to make a call :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an easy way to calculate that metric, but hopefully this will help. Without some sort of SQL cursor, I would generate a SQL table of possible intervals, with start and end timestamps (2009-09-02T00:00 to 2009-09-02T00:59, 2009-09-02T00:01 to 2009-09-02T01:00, etc) and then cross join using LINQ to SQL:

```
var rates = from r in db.Reviews
            from i in db.Intervals
            where i.Begin <= r.Timestamp && r.Timestamp <= i.End
            group r by i.Begin into reviews
            select reviews.Count();
var maxRate = rates.Max();
```

I haven't tried the code, but it should get you started. You could improve the performance by restricting how far back to check (last 7 days, 30 days, etc) or generate fewer intervals (starting on the quarter hour, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

If you're instead wanting "*which product got the most reviews in a 60 minute block between dateX and dateY*" then it gets a little more complex.

One way to think of it is "*for each review in that time period how many other reviews are there for the same product ID in the following 60 minutes*". Once you have that logic the query becomes clearer:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    PR.ProductID,
    -- start of 60 minute block
    PR.Timestamp,
    ReviewCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ProductReviews PR1
        -- from parent time
        WHERE PR1.Timestamp >= PR.Timestamp
        -- until 60 mins later
        AND PR1.Timestamp <= DATEADD( minute, 60, PR.Timestamp )
        -- that matches ProductID
        AND PR1.ProductID = PR.ProductID
    )
FROM ProductReviews PR
-- in the last 24 hours
WHERE PR.Timestamp > ( GETDATE() - 1 )
ORDER BY ReviewCount DESC
```

Hows that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a set 60 minute time block (e.g. the last 60 minutes from now) then it's reasonably easy:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    PR.ProductID,
    COUNT(*)
FROM ProductReviews PR
WHERE PR.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD( minute, -60, GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY PR.ProductID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you're wanting it for any 60 minute interval then it gets more complex!

Comment: preferably looking for a rolling 60 minute window but may have to settle with fixed hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you were happy with fixed-hours for your windows, I may consider doing this a little bit smarter, by using a trigger. The trigger would insert/update into a 'log' table, and just differentiate between inserting or updating based on the current time.

You could combine with this any of the other approaches, it would add a nice caching layer.